Can not make SQL request of django field in Postgresql database
I have a django model named Interface and created in Postgresql DB?
Some char fiels are stored as  extended and i can SQL SELECT requests can not find those columns (error bellow).
Please someone knows how to solve this ?
BR,
Error
SELECT deviceIp  FROM home_interface limit 2;
ERROR:  column "deviceip" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT deviceIp  FROM home_interface limit 2;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "home_interface.deviceIp".

Models
class Interface(models.Model):
    deviceIp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ifAlias =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ifDescription = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    deviceName = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    ifIndex = models.IntegerField(default=0.0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['deviceIp']
        unique_together = ('deviceIp', 'ifIndex')

\d+ home_interface
    Column     |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   | Storage  | Compr
ession | Stats target | Description
---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+----------+------
-------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer                |           | not null | nextval('home_interface_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |
       |              |
 deviceIp      | character varying(100) |           | not null |                                            | extended |
       |              |
 ifAlias       | character varying(100) |           | not null |                                            | extended |
       |              |
 ifDescription | character varying(100) |           | not null |                                            | extended |
       |              |
 deviceName    | character varying(100) |           | not null |                                            | extended |
       |              |
 ifIndex       | integer                |           | not null |                                            | plain    |
       |              |
 name          | character varying(100) |           | not null |                                            | extended |
       |              |
 in_bw         | double precision       |           | not null |                                            | plain    |
       |              |
 out_bw        | double precision       |           | not null |                                            | plain    |
       |              |
 is_monitored  | boolean                |           | not null |                                            | plain    |
       |              |
Indexes:
    "home_interface_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "home_interface_deviceIp_ifIndex_22fa8640_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree ("deviceIp", "ifIndex")
Referenced by:
    TABLE "home_router_interfaces" CONSTRAINT "home_router_interfac_interface_id_55713e19_fk_home_inte" FOREIGN KEY (interface
_id) REFERENCES home_interface(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Access method: heap



Looks more like some database setting.

PostgreSQL columns are case sensitive so you need to double quote your column name, also your question is missing where and how you do the query

Thanks @iklinac that was the issue
